# Error creating RegionNetworkEndpointGroup: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.regionNetworkEndpointGroups.create' permission for 'projects/myproj

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

On **GCP**, I'm trying to create **a Serverless Network Endpoint Group** for **Cloud Run** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "cloudrun_neg" {
  name                  = "neg"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = "asia-northeast1"
  cloud_run {
    service = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
  }
}
```

But I got this error below:

> Error creating RegionNetworkEndpointGroup: googleapi: Error 403:
> Required 'compute.regionNetworkEndpointGroups.create' permission for
> 'projects/myproject-813731/regions/asia-northeast1/networkEndpointGroups/neg',
> forbidden

So now, I'm trying to add a role to solve this error above but there are too many roles to choose:

[image]

What role do I need to choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose the role either **"Compute Instance Admin (v1)"**:

[image]

Or **"Compute Instance Admin (beta)"** to create **a Serverless Network Endpoint Group** for **Cloud Run**:

[image]

In addition, you can choose the more abstract role **"Compute Admin"** to create **a Serverless Network Endpoint Group** for **Cloud Run**:

[image]